# Create control dates in bilateral case crossover design

Tags: r, sas, stata

I am planning to study the effects of air pollution on emergency room visit and I intend to use a bilateral case crossover design. For each case (hospital visit) I would like to create 4 control dates (7 and 14 days before and after the visit). For instance, if a person visits a clinic on September 10, 2012 my controls will be Aug 27, Sep 03, Sep 17 and Sep 24. The following example illustrates what I have and what I want to achieve.

Any thought on how to undertake this in SAS, Stata or R  would be highly appreciated

Sample data (all are visit dates)

```
id  date  
-------------
1   04-jan-05
2   05-jan-05
3   05-jan-05
4   06-jan-05
5   06-feb-05
```

What I would like to achieve (for each `id` there is one case and 4 controls)

```
id  date        outcome
---------------------------
1   21-Dec-04   control
1   28-Dec-04   control
1   04-Jan-05   case
1   11-Jan-05   control
1   18-Jan-05   control
2   22-Dec-04   control
2   29-Dec-04   control
2   05-Jan-05   case
2   12-Jan-05   control
2   19-Jan-05   control
3   22-Dec-04   control
3   29-Dec-04   control
3   05-Jan-05   case
3   12-Jan-05   control
3   19-Jan-05   control
4   23-Dec-04   control
4   30-Dec-04   control
4   06-Jan-05   case
4   13-Jan-05   control
4   20-Jan-05   control
5   23-Jan-05   control
5   30-Jan-05   control
5   06-Feb-05   case
5   13-Feb-05   control
5   20-Feb-05   control
```

Comment: The package [`season`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/season/index.html) has a whole suite of functions for use with `R`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple loop will produce the output you want.

```
data have;
input id  date :date10.;
format date date9.;
datalines;
1   04-jan-05
2   05-jan-05
3   05-jan-05
4   06-jan-05
5   06-feb-05
;
run;

data want (drop=i date rename=(date1=date));
set have;
format date1 date9.;
length outcome $8;
do i=-14 to 14 by 7;
    date1=date+i;
    outcome=ifc(i=0,'case','control');
    output;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one R solution:

```
# Your data
visits <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "id  date  
1   04-jan-05
2   05-jan-05
3   05-jan-05
4   06-jan-05
5   06-feb-05")

# Convert $date to a date format
visits$date <- as.Date(visits$date, format="%d-%b-%y")
```

To get your output as a list (which might be useful in certain situations):

```
lapply(1:nrow(visits), 
       function(x) 
         data.frame(id = visits$id[x], 
                    dates = visits$date[x] + seq(-14, 14, 7), 
                    outcome = c("control", "control", "case", 
                                "control", "control")))
```

Or, if you prefer a single `data.frame`, the same, plus a `do.call(rbind, ...)`:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(1:nrow(visits), 
               function(x) 
                 data.frame(id = visits$id[x], 
                            dates = visits$date[x] + seq(-14, 14, 7), 
                            outcome = c("control", "control", "case", 
                                        "control", "control"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Stata solution:

```
input byte id str9 sdate 
  1   04-jan-05
  2   05-jan-05
  3   05-jan-05
  4   06-jan-05
  5   06-feb-05
end 
generate long ndate = date(sdate,"DMY",2050)
expand 5
bysort id: replace ndate = ndate + (_n-3)*7
generate byte case = (ndate == date(sdate,"DMY",2050))
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I get dates like `16426`. I've only tested on Stata 11.

Comment: Ok. I got slightly more reader-friendly output by adding `format ndate %td` to your commands.

Comment: That's Unix dates in Stata. See `help dates`.