# How to make a case crossover data in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

## Creat a reproducible data

```
set.seed(20220105)
begin = as.Date('1994-01-01')
end   = as.Date('1994-12-31')
date_seq = seq(from = begin, to = end, by = '1 day')
length = length(date_seq)
death = sample(x = 1:100, size = length, replace = T)
temperature = sample(x = -25:25, size = length, replace = T)

df = data.frame(date = date_seq, death = death, temperature = temperature)
> head(df)
        date death temperature
1 1994-01-01    66          20
2 1994-01-02    56           7
3 1994-01-03    33          -9
4 1994-01-04    29         -17
5 1994-01-05     6           0
6 1994-01-06    33         -15
```

## Variable definition

Each day in `df` can be a **case day** and also can be a **control day**.

The **case day** and **control days** are matched by day of the week in the same month and in the same year.

Thus, each case has 3 or 4 control days (before and/or after the case day in the same month).

For example, when the case day is `1994-01-01`, control days are `1994-01-08`, `1994-01-15`, `1994-01-22` and `1994-01-29`.
When the case day is `1994-01-08`, control days are `1994-01-01`, `1994-01-15`, `1994-01-22` and `1994-01-29`.

## What I needed

I want to creat a new `df_wanted` that based on the original `df`.

`df_wanted` should contain 5 varibales which 3 variables from the original `df` including `date`, `death` and `temperature`.

The `death` and `temperature` should be the **case day**'s `death` and `temperature`.

The other 2 varibales are new variables.

One is `status` which indicates a day is `case day` or `control day`.

One is `stratum`. This variable like a group. Each group has one case day and three or four control day.

Some of the data in `df_wanted` should like this:

```
df_wanted = data.frame(
date = c('1994-01-01', '1994-01-08', '1994-01-15', '1994-01-22', '1994-01-29',
         '1994-01-08', '1994-01-01', '1994-01-15', '1994-01-22', '1994-01-29'),
status = c(1,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0),
stratum = c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2),
death = c(66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 1,1,1,1,1),
temperature = c(20,20,20,20,20, 13,13,13,13,13)
)
> df_wanted
         date status stratum death temperature
1  1994-01-01      1       1    66          20
2  1994-01-08      0       1    66          20
3  1994-01-15      0       1    66          20
4  1994-01-22      0       1    66          20
5  1994-01-29      0       1    66          20
6  1994-01-08      1       2     1          13
7  1994-01-01      0       2     1          13
8  1994-01-15      0       2     1          13
9  1994-01-22      0       2     1          13
10 1994-01-29      0       2     1          13
```

## What I have tried

I searched some answers, such as [Create control dates in bilateral case crossover design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350661/create-control-dates-in-bilateral-case-crossover-design) and [Create a case control pair for time stratified case-crossover design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676779/create-a-case-control-pair-for-time-stratified-case-crossover-design), but all the answers do not meet my need.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `full_join` the dataset with itself by the same day of week, month and year. Here is a `dplyr` approach.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    id = seq_len(n()), 
    ymw = format(date, "%Y-%m-%w")
  ) %>% 
  full_join(., ., by = "ymw") %>% 
  transmute(
    stratum = id.x, 
    date = date.y, 
    status = +(id.x == id.y), 
    death = death.x, 
    temperature = temperature.x
  )
```

Output

```
   stratum       date status death temperature
1        1 1994-01-01      1    66          20
2        1 1994-01-08      0    66          20
3        1 1994-01-15      0    66          20
4        1 1994-01-22      0    66          20
5        1 1994-01-29      0    66          20
6        2 1994-01-02      1    56           7
7        2 1994-01-09      0    56           7
8        2 1994-01-16      0    56           7
9        2 1994-01-23      0    56           7
10       2 1994-01-30      0    56           7
11       3 1994-01-03      1    33          -9
12       3 1994-01-10      0    33          -9
13       3 1994-01-17      0    33          -9
14       3 1994-01-24      0    33          -9
15       3 1994-01-31      0    33          -9
16       4 1994-01-04      1    29         -17
17       4 1994-01-11      0    29         -17
18       4 1994-01-18      0    29         -17
19       4 1994-01-25      0    29         -17
20       5 1994-01-05      1     6           0
21       5 1994-01-12      0     6           0
22       5 1994-01-19      0     6           0
23       5 1994-01-26      0     6           0
24       6 1994-01-06      1    33         -15
25       6 1994-01-13      0    33         -15
26       6 1994-01-20      0    33         -15
27       6 1994-01-27      0    33         -15
28       7 1994-01-07      1    31          21
29       7 1994-01-14      0    31          21
30       7 1994-01-21      0    31          21
31       7 1994-01-28      0    31          21
32       8 1994-01-01      0     1          13
33       8 1994-01-08      1     1          13
34       8 1994-01-15      0     1          13
35       8 1994-01-22      0     1          13
36       8 1994-01-29      0     1          13
37       9 1994-01-02      0    83           4
38       9 1994-01-09      1    83           4
39       9 1994-01-16      0    83           4
40       9 1994-01-23      0    83           4
41       9 1994-01-30      0    83           4
42      10 1994-01-03      0    37           7
43      10 1994-01-10      1    37           7
44      10 1994-01-17      0    37           7
45      10 1994-01-24      0    37           7
46      10 1994-01-31      0    37           7
47      11 1994-01-04      0    94         -18
48      11 1994-01-11      1    94         -18
49      11 1994-01-18      0    94         -18
50      11 1994-01-25      0    94         -18
51      12 1994-01-05      0    46           3
52      12 1994-01-12      1    46           3
53      12 1994-01-19      0    46           3
54      12 1994-01-26      0    46           3
55      13 1994-01-06      0    45         -13
56      13 1994-01-13      1    45         -13
57      13 1994-01-20      0    45         -13
58      13 1994-01-27      0    45         -13
59      14 1994-01-07      0    47         -21
60      14 1994-01-14      1    47         -21
61      14 1994-01-21      0    47         -21
62      14 1994-01-28      0    47         -21
63      15 1994-01-01      0    38           3
64      15 1994-01-08      0    38           3
65      15 1994-01-15      1    38           3
66      15 1994-01-22      0    38           3
67      15 1994-01-29      0    38           3
68      16 1994-01-02      0    96         -25
69      16 1994-01-09      0    96         -25
70      16 1994-01-16      1    96         -25
71      16 1994-01-23      0    96         -25
72      16 1994-01-30      0    96         -25
73      17 1994-01-03      0    99          20
74      17 1994-01-10      0    99          20
75      17 1994-01-17      1    99          20
76      17 1994-01-24      0    99          20
77      17 1994-01-31      0    99          20
78      18 1994-01-04      0    33         -22
79      18 1994-01-11      0    33         -22
80      18 1994-01-18      1    33         -22
81      18 1994-01-25      0    33         -22
82      19 1994-01-05      0    46          10
83      19 1994-01-12      0    46          10
84      19 1994-01-19      1    46          10
85      19 1994-01-26      0    46          10
86      20 1994-01-06      0    60          -2
87      20 1994-01-13      0    60          -2
88      20 1994-01-20      1    60          -2
89      20 1994-01-27      0    60          -2
90      21 1994-01-07      0    43          16
91      21 1994-01-14      0    43          16
92      21 1994-01-21      1    43          16
93      21 1994-01-28      0    43          16
94      22 1994-01-01      0    81         -14
95      22 1994-01-08      0    81         -14
96      22 1994-01-15      0    81         -14
97      22 1994-01-22      1    81         -14
98      22 1994-01-29      0    81         -14
99      23 1994-01-02      0    67          25
100     23 1994-01-09      0    67          25
101     23 1994-01-16      0    67          25
102     23 1994-01-23      1    67          25
103     23 1994-01-30      0    67          25
104     24 1994-01-03      0    31          23
105     24 1994-01-10      0    31          23
106     24 1994-01-17      0    31          23
107     24 1994-01-24      1    31          23
108     24 1994-01-31      0    31          23
109     25 1994-01-04      0    25           0
110     25 1994-01-11      0    25           0
111     25 1994-01-18      0    25           0
112     25 1994-01-25      1    25           0
113     26 1994-01-05      0    51         -21
114     26 1994-01-12      0    51         -21
115     26 1994-01-19      0    51         -21
116     26 1994-01-26      1    51         -21
117     27 1994-01-06      0    37           5
118     27 1994-01-13      0    37           5
119     27 1994-01-20      0    37           5
120     27 1994-01-27      1    37           5
121     28 1994-01-07      0     3          13
122     28 1994-01-14      0     3          13
123     28 1994-01-21      0     3          13
124     28 1994-01-28      1     3          13
125     29 1994-01-01      0    69         -22
126     29 1994-01-08      0    69         -22
127     29 1994-01-15      0    69         -22
128     29 1994-01-22      0    69         -22
129     29 1994-01-29      1    69         -22
130     30 1994-01-02      0    51          12
131     30 1994-01-09      0    51          12
132     30 1994-01-16      0    51          12
133     30 1994-01-23      0    51          12
134     30 1994-01-30      1    51          12
135     31 1994-01-03      0    84          17
136     31 1994-01-10      0    84          17
137     31 1994-01-17      0    84          17
138     31 1994-01-24      0    84          17
139     31 1994-01-31      1    84          17
140     32 1994-02-01      1    10           4
141     32 1994-02-08      0    10           4
142     32 1994-02-15      0    10           4
143     32 1994-02-22      0    10           4
144     33 1994-02-02      1    67          10
145     33 1994-02-09      0    67          10
146     33 1994-02-16      0    67          10
147     33 1994-02-23      0    67          10
148     34 1994-02-03      1    61         -21
149     34 1994-02-10      0    61         -21
150     34 1994-02-17      0    61         -21
151     34 1994-02-24      0    61         -21
152     35 1994-02-04      1    11           7
153     35 1994-02-11      0    11           7
154     35 1994-02-18      0    11           7
155     35 1994-02-25      0    11           7
156     36 1994-02-05      1    15         -21
157     36 1994-02-12      0    15         -21
158     36 1994-02-19      0    15         -21
159     36 1994-02-26      0    15         -21
160     37 1994-02-06      1    78          21
161     37 1994-02-13      0    78          21
162     37 1994-02-20      0    78          21
163     37 1994-02-27      0    78          21
164     38 1994-02-07      1    67          11
165     38 1994-02-14      0    67          11
166     38 1994-02-21      0    67          11
167     38 1994-02-28      0    67          11
168     39 1994-02-01      0    89         -10
169     39 1994-02-08      1    89         -10
170     39 1994-02-15      0    89         -10
171     39 1994-02-22      0    89         -10
172     40 1994-02-02      0    70          11
173     40 1994-02-09      1    70          11
174     40 1994-02-16      0    70          11
175     40 1994-02-23      0    70          11
176     41 1994-02-03      0    95          25
177     41 1994-02-10      1    95          25
178     41 1994-02-17      0    95          25
179     41 1994-02-24      0    95          25
180     42 1994-02-04      0    75          22
181     42 1994-02-11      1    75          22
182     42 1994-02-18      0    75          22
183     42 1994-02-25      0    75          22
184     43 1994-02-05      0    99         -20
185     43 1994-02-12      1    99         -20
186     43 1994-02-19      0    99         -20
187     43 1994-02-26      0    99         -20
188     44 1994-02-06      0    99           7
189     44 1994-02-13      1    99           7
190     44 1994-02-20      0    99           7
191     44 1994-02-27      0    99           7
192     45 1994-02-07      0    62          -2
193     45 1994-02-14      1    62          -2
194     45 1994-02-21      0    62          -2
195     45 1994-02-28      0    62          -2
196     46 1994-02-01      0    50          -9
197     46 1994-02-08      0    50          -9
198     46 1994-02-15      1    50          -9
199     46 1994-02-22      0    50          -9
200     47 1994-02-02      0    99         -13
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1405 rows ]
```

Comment: Thanks @ ekoam, it's really a good answer.